# storing and retrieving hashed password in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, bcrypt

I am watching a tutorial on FastAPI, where it switched the database from SQLite to PostgreSQL, before generating a token. It was working before but now it has an error, shown below

`return bcrypt.checkpw(password=password_byte_enc, hashed_password=hashed_password) TypeError: argument 'hashed_password': 'str' object cannot be converted to 'PyBytes'`

I think this is the code concerning the error:

```
def get_password_hash(password):
    # return bcrypt_context.hash(password)
    pwd_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password=pwd_bytes, salt=salt)
    return hashed_password


def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    password_byte_enc = plain_password.encode('utf-8')
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password=password_byte_enc, hashed_password=hashed_password)
```

The entirity of the auth.py file is here https://pastebin.com/mHcd0YLU

This is where I input the username and password to generate a token but it gets an error:
[image: username and password input]

Comment: It's complaining about `hashed_password` not being a byte string - you're only converting the plain text password. The reason why this changes is because you probably have differing column types in sqlite vs postgres, or their libraries convert those column types to different python types.

Comment: @MatsLindh when i created the column in postgres it is `hashed_password varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL` i tried also convertion using `hashed_password = hashed_password.encode('utf-8')` `but it gave me an error invalid salt

Comment: yes, `varchar` will be returned as str - but you might want to look at what `hashed_password` contains then, and verify that it's in the expected format (and that it doesn't suddenly include `b'...'` in the actual string - which can happen if you just use `str` on a bytes sequence before storing it.

Comment: @MatsLindh looking at pgadmin the hash password is stored as `\x2432622431322475325a7444453836457945747a726b43477a5a484c4f2e594e497477395872566f6f666b2f69633642486b366f494e7450395a6c79`

Comment: You'll want to confirm what you're getting back from postgres, not what pgadmin is displaying to you (that's a binary value being displayed). Those are hexadecimal values that describe the byte values in your string, so it comes down to what you've actually stored and what you're actually retrieving, and what stage of the process where the problem is. `\x24\x32\x62\x24\x31\x32` is `$2b$12` when decoded, which seems to be the start of the expected hash format.

Comment: @MatsLindh so used a print to check the user pass input and the db pass, the user pass input does indeed have a `b` at the start, the password is `test1234!` when it is printed in the terminal it is `b'test1234!'`, im a beginner at this so i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: the hash value is the same when printed `\x2432622431322475325a7444453836457945747a726b43477a5a484c4f2e594e497477395872566f6f666b2f69633642486b366f494e7450395a6c79`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
after hashing, using the decode property is needed to store correctly the hash password in the postgres database

```
def get_password_hash(password):
    pwd_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password=pwd_bytes, salt=salt)
    string_password = hashed_password.decode('utf8')
    return string_password


def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    password_byte_enc = plain_password.encode('utf-8')
    hashed_password = hashed_password.encode('utf-8')
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password_byte_enc, hashed_password)
```

if any other has a better solution i am open for it